# Google Analytics Tracking a sub-directory which itself is pointed to by a separate domain in DNS

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I have an existing website pointed to by the domain www.xyz.com . We are now creating a new sub-site to this www.xyz.com/ab/. We have another regional domain www.abc.rg purchased and we want to point this domain to the /ab/ sub-folder. 
The queries are:

1. If I want to do this at the DNS level is it going to be an issue in terms of SEO?
2. If I do so how can I add Google tracking to it? I want to continue using my existing tracking for www.xyz.com and provide reports separately for www.abc.rg.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question here.

Comment: I want to know if part two in my question is doable in google analytics.

Comment: This question is better suited to [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), you better ask there.